# BufferedReader, csv, how to pass int as parameter (parameter is an object)

Tags: java, object, parameters, hashmap, bufferedreader

I'm trying to turn the String within my file that gets fed through buffered reader into a link to the object required (cards, object) as a parameter for the creation of a new object (purchase).

1. My cards are stored within a hashmap.
2. My purchases are stored within a hashmap.
3. My cards are loaded into the program using buffered reader upon startup.
4. My purchases *will be/trying to be* loaded into the program using buffered reader upon startup.

The error is

> no suitable method found for put(int,cards)
>           method Map.put(Integer,purchase) is not applicable
>             (argument mismatch; cards cannot be converted to purchase)
>           method AbstractMap.put(Integer,purchase) is not applicable
>             (argument mismatch; cards cannot be converted to purchase)
>           method HashMap.put(Integer,purchase) is not applicable
>             (argument mismatch; cards cannot be converted to purchase)

Here is my purchase class:

```
public class purchase

{
    int receiptId;
    cards cards1;
    int time;
        private double men; 
        private double women;
        private double kids;
        private double home;
        private double sport;

        public purchase(int receiptId, cards cards1, double men, double women, double kids, double home, double sport)
    {
            this.receiptId = receiptId;
            this.cards1 = cards1;
            this.men = men;
            this.women = women;
            this.kids = kids;
            this.home = home;
            this.sport = sport;
        }
```

Here is the HashMap creation:

```
 private static HashMap<Integer, purchase> purchaseMap = new HashMap<Integer, purchase>(); 
    private static HashMap<Integer, cards> map = new HashMap<Integer, cards>();
```

Here is one of the type of cards code (basicCard extends RegisteredCards, registeredcards extends cards).

```
public class basicCard extends registeredCards

{
        private String name;
        private String email;
        double balance;
        int id;
        double points;

    public basicCard(String name, String email, double balance, int id, double points)
    {
            super(name, email, balance, id, points);
            this.name = name;
            this.email = email;
            this.balance = balance;
            this.id = id;
            this.points = points;   
    }
```

Here is the csv .txt file for cards

```
b,basictestnew1,email@email.com,0.0,1,0.0
p,basictestnew1,email@email.com,0.0,2,0.0
a,0.0,3,0.0
```

Here is the csv .txt file for purchases

```
1,null,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0
2,1,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0
3,2,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0
```

Here are the BufferedReaders for both cards and purchases

```
try 
    {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("cardData.txt")); 
        String line;
        line = in.readLine ();
        while (line != null)   
            {
                String[] field = line.split(",");
                if ( field[0] .equals("b") )
                {
                    basicCard b2 = new basicCard(field[1], field[2], Double.parseDouble(field[3]), Integer.parseInt(field[4]), Double.parseDouble(field[5]));
                    System.out.println("Basic card created after BufferedReader split");
                    map.put(b2.getid(), b2);
                    cardsList.add(b2.getid()); 
                    line = in.readLine ();
                }
                else if ( field[0] .equals("p") )
                {    
                    premiumCard p2 = new premiumCard(field[1], field[2], Double.parseDouble(field[3]), Integer.parseInt(field[4]), Double.parseDouble(field[5]));
                    System.out.println("Premium card created after BufferedReader split"); 
                    map.put(p2.getid(), p2);
                    cardsList.add(p2.getid());
                    line = in.readLine();
                }
                else if ( field[0] .equals("a") )
                {     
                    anonCard a2 = new anonCard(Double.parseDouble(field[1]),Integer.parseInt(field[2]),Double.parseDouble(field[3]));    
                    System.out.println("Anon card created after buffered reader split");
                    map.put(a2.getid(), a2);
                    cardsList.add(a2.getid()); 
                    line = in.readLine();
                }
            }
        in.close ();

        BufferedReader in1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("purchaseData.txt")); 
        String line1; 
        line1 = in1.readLine();
        while (line1 != null )
        {
            String[] field1 = line.split(",");
            int cardInt; 
            int receiptId;
            receiptId = Integer.parseInt(field1[0]); 
            cards cards3;
            cardInt = Integer.parseInt(field1[1]);
            cards3 = map.get(cardInt);
            purchase p2 = new purchase(Integer.parseInt(field1[0]), map.get(cardInt), Double.parseDouble(field1[2]), Double.parseDouble(field1[3]), Double.parseDouble(field1[4]), Double.parseDouble(field1[5]), Double.parseDouble(field1[6]));
            purchaseMap.put(receiptId, cards3);
        }
        in1.close(); 
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage()); 
    }
```

Comment: What exactly goes wrong?

Comment: from exception: *method Map.put(Integer,purchase) is not applicable (argument mismatch; cards cannot be converted to purchase)*, you are putting a card object into purchase value, which is not applicable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code

```
BufferedReader in1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("purchaseData.txt")); 
String line1; 
line1 = in1.readLine();
while (line1 != null )
{
    String[] field1 = line.split(",");
    int cardInt; 
    int receiptId;
    receiptId = Integer.parseInt(field1[0]); 
    cards cards3;
    cardInt = Integer.parseInt(field1[1]);
    cards3 = map.get(cardInt);
    purchase p2 = new purchase(Integer.parseInt(field1[0]), map.get(cardInt), Double.parseDouble(field1[2]), Double.parseDouble(field1[3]), Double.parseDouble(field1[4]), Double.parseDouble(field1[5]), Double.parseDouble(field1[6]));
    purchaseMap.put(receiptId, cards3);
}
```

here you are trying to put **cards3 object(which is cards type)**  in purchaseMap where **purchaseMap** allows to put **purchase type object**.

you will not get error if you code like **purchaseMap.put(receiptId, p2);**

where **p2 is purchase type object**.

Just replace the **cards3** by **p2**.

Your code should look like below

```
BufferedReader in1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("purchaseData.txt")); 
String line1; 
line1 = in1.readLine();
while (line1 != null )
{
    String[] field1 = line.split(",");
    int cardInt; 
    int receiptId;
    receiptId = Integer.parseInt(field1[0]); 
    cards cards3;
    cardInt = Integer.parseInt(field1[1]);
    cards3 = map.get(cardInt);
    purchase p2 = new purchase(Integer.parseInt(field1[0]), map.get(cardInt), Double.parseDouble(field1[2]), Double.parseDouble(field1[3]), Double.parseDouble(field1[4]), Double.parseDouble(field1[5]), Double.parseDouble(field1[6]));
    purchaseMap.put(receiptId, p2);
}
```